# In C, how do I convert 1-channel PCM into 2-channel PCM?

Tags: c, linux, audio, pcm, libsndfile

I am using libao and libsndfile to read and play audio.  I would like to convert a monaural stream into a stereo stream by copying one channel into two.  This test code will play a stereo clip  correctly, but will play a monaural one very fast and high-pitched.  Additionally I'm getting a "double free or corruption" on the `free(output);` call.  What am I doing wrong?

```
/* Converting a 1-channel stream to 2-channels
 * compile with "gcc -o stereoize stereoize.c -lao -lsndfile"
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 512

void stereoize(short *, short *, size_t);
void playfile(FILE *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(2);
    }

    playfile(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Finished.\n");

    return 0;
}

void playfile(FILE *fp)
{
    int default_driver;
    int frames_read;
    int count;
    int toread;
    short *buffer;
    short *output;

    ao_device *device;
    ao_sample_format format;

    SNDFILE     *sndfile;
    SF_INFO     sf_info;


    ao_initialize();
    default_driver = ao_default_driver_id();

    sf_info.format = 0;

    sndfile = sf_open_fd(fileno(fp), SFM_READ, &sf_info, 0);

    memset(&format, 0, sizeof(ao_sample_format));

    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    format.bits = 16;
    format.rate = sf_info.samplerate;
    //    format.channels = sf_info.channels;
    format.channels = 2;

    printf("Channels: %d\n", sf_info.channels);
    printf("Samplerate: %d\n", sf_info.samplerate);

    if (sf_info.channels > 2 || sf_info.channels < 1) {
        printf("Sorry.  Only 1 or 2 channels, please.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL);
    if (device == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening sound device.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffer = malloc(BUFFSIZE * sf_info.channels * sizeof(short));
    output = malloc(BUFFSIZE * 2 * sizeof(short));

    frames_read = 0;
    toread = sf_info.frames * sf_info.channels;

    while (toread > 0) {
    if (toread < BUFFSIZE * sf_info.channels)
        count = toread;
    else
        count = BUFFSIZE * sf_info.channels;

        frames_read = sf_read_short(sndfile, buffer, count);

    if (sf_info.channels == 1)
        stereoize(output, buffer, count);
    else
        memcpy(output, buffer, count * sizeof(short));

    if (sf_info.channels == 1)
            ao_play(device, (char *)output, 2 * frames_read * sizeof(short));
    else
            ao_play(device, (char *)output, frames_read * sizeof(short));

    toread = toread - frames_read;
    }

    free(buffer);
    free(output);
    ao_close(device);
    sf_close(sndfile);
    ao_shutdown();

    return;
}

void stereoize(short *outbuf, short *inbuf, size_t length)
{
    int count;
    int outcount;

    outcount = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
        outbuf[outcount] = outbuf[outcount+1] = inbuf[count];
        outcount += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a loop condition such as `count <= length` (like you do in the loop in `stereoize`) is in most cases not what you want as it will go out of bounds. And being out of bounds of allocated memory of course leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This line: 'if (argc < 1) {' is not correct.  if NO parameters, then argc ==1.  If 1 parameter, then argc == 2.  and since the code wants exactly one parameter, suggest: 'if (argc != 2) {'

Comment: the variable: 'readnow' is not used.  This line: 'filestart = ftell(fp);' will always return 0, so can be eliminated.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.  The returned value from: 'playfile()' is being ignored.

Comment: for readabillity by humans and for consistency, the code block after 'while (toread >0)' should be indented

Comment: If you are getting "double free or corruption" warnings you should fix that before doing anything else. You should also compile with -Wall and fix all compiler warnings.

Comment: I fixed the "double free or corruption" problem yesterday.  I'm still having a problem with rates below 44100 Hz playing fast and squeaky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `stereoize(output, buffer, count * sizeof(short));`, is most probably causing the problem. `stereoize` function expects number of samples as `length` parameter, but you are passing the total block size in bytes. Change it to `stereoize(output, buffer, count);`, See if it solves the problem.
Also check @Joachim Pileborg's comment.

Comment: I applied all suggested changes.  The double-free problem is solved, but playing 1-channel files still results in a squeaky and sped-up version of what's really in the file.

Comment: @Frotz, `frames_read` is the number of frames actually read, which you are doubling artificially (in *mono* case). So, the total block size passed to the `ao_play` function should be changed to `2 * frames_read * sizeof(short)` for `sf_info.channels == 1` case. This should fix both the squeakiness and increased-pace of playback.

Comment: @B. Shakar.  With the 1 and 2 channel problem solved, another one has emerged that was probably masked by the former.  Samples taken at 11025 Hz play fast and squeaky regardless of bitness or channels.

Comment: @Frotz, That seems strange. But anyways if that's true, you should try finding out what's so special about 11025 Hz. Have you tried different rates and the problem occurs only with 11025 Hz?

Comment: @B. Shakar.  All sample rates below 44100 Hz sound wrong.  Rates above 44100 Hz sound okay.